# Throw exceptions in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a mortgage calculator in Java.  I have to validate the data using try and catch blocks.  I have done the rest of the program, but I can't figure out how to implement the try and catch blocks.  Here's what the prompt is asking for:

"Write your own exceptions to validate your data by using try and catch blocks. For example loan amount cannot be a negative number and it should be between $5000 and $1,000,000."

Edit: Here's the try-catch block that finally worked. It needed to be placed in the actionPerformed method where the rest of my data is. I had another issue where the code kept throwing an exception for any amount that I entered until I figured out that I needed to place the for loop inside of the try block.

```
try 
    {
      if((n1 < 5000) || (n1 > 1000000))
      throw new Exception();   

      for (int i = 0; i < term[0] * 12; i++)
      {   
        double interest_paid = n1 * (rate[0] / 12);
        double principal_paid = tr1 - interest_paid;
        n1 = n1 - principal_paid;

        //Prints the results.
        edit.append("\n  " + (i+1) + " \t\t " + (two.format(interest_paid)) 
            + " \t\t " + (two.format(principal_paid)) + " \t\t "
                + (two.format(Math.abs(n1))));            
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {        
      edit.setText("Please enter an amount between $5,000 and $1,000,000.");       
      mortText.setText("");
      out.setText("");                 
    }
```

Comment: Click the "edit" link? In any case, it's pretty hard to read even with correct indentation. It's not clear what the question is--validate and if there's a validation error, throw an exception. Put wherever you call the validations into a `try` block that catches the exception and proceeds appropriately. What's the specific issue?

Comment: you have not attempted anything. let's see your effort so far

Comment: @Moose In general we try to keep questions as just that, questions--not unrelated commentary :) Ghost Worker's comment is aimed at there not being any try/catch statements anywhere at all. In other words, *try* something. "How to do it" I pretty much explained in my first comment--hence asking what the *specific* issue is.

Comment: Have you read [_The Java Tutorials_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)' lesson on [Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) yet?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide a [mcve].  For starters, your question has nothing to do with Swing, so the gobs of `JScrollPane` and `JMenuItem` code are just distractions from your real concern.  Or, to put it another way, if you can't figure out `try`-`except` blocks _at all_, how will you possibly make sense of them when they're mixed up with GUI elements and the Swing events queue?

Comment: [I've refactored your code](https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/29aaa83fed17b6569461e383ae06b576) in order to make any sense of it. There's still cleanup to do. If you hand in my refactored code your teacher will know you cheated. That said: the only place any parsing happens is here: https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/29aaa83fed17b6569461e383ae06b576#file-guts-java-L13 If you wrap it in a try/catch, and handle the exception in a reasonable way,  you'll be done--depending on what your actual requirements are. You'll have to fit it into your code in a reasonable way.

Comment: @Kevin J. Chase I have read through our class handout on Exceptions.  You identified a general problem I have with coding: how to combine new code into a program.  Although I understand the concept and structure of try-catch blocks, I get confused on how it interfaces w/ other elements, how to access the variables I need, etc.

Comment: @Dave Newton I guess the biggest issue I'm having with this code is how to get the mortText variable (which holds the mortgage amount) into the try-catch block to perform the data validation.  You gave me some good clues to go on.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dave Newton Hey Dave, I edited my code with the try-catch block.  If you would be kind enough to take a look at it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Moose [More refactoring](https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/29aaa83fed17b6569461e383ae06b576#file-morerefactors-java) breaks apart each separate task. You need to handle exceptions thrown by `parseDouble` -- look at its Javadocs to see what exceptions it may throw. You have two sets of conditions: bad parsing, and bad amounts. You *could* throw a standard exception, but in general, wrap those up in custom, app-specific exceptions to avoid having to catch many different exceptions, and to tailor your code to your specific app requirements.

Comment: @Dave Newton  I updated my post with the try-catch block that I finally got to work.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Kevin J. Chase Thanks Kevin, I went ahead and did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the try-catch block that finally worked. It needed to be placed in the actionPerformed method where the rest of my data is. I had another issue where the code kept throwing an exception for any amount that I entered until I figured out that I needed to place the for loop inside of the try block.

```
try 
{
if((n1 < 5000) || (n1 > 1000000))
  throw new Exception();   

  for (int i = 0; i < term[0] * 12; i++)
  {   
    double interest_paid = n1 * (rate[0] / 12);
    double principal_paid = tr1 - interest_paid;
    n1 = n1 - principal_paid;

    //Prints the results.
    edit.append("\n  " + (i+1) + " \t\t " + (two.format(interest_paid)) 
        + " \t\t " + (two.format(principal_paid)) + " \t\t "
            + (two.format(Math.abs(n1))));            
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{        
  edit.setText("Please enter an amount between $5,000 and $1,000,000.");       
  mortText.setText("");
  out.setText("");                 
}
```